# Creating different XML files depending on the existence of others c#

Tags: c#, xml, saving-data

having an issue when saving data, I am trying to set it up so if the user tries to save their name data for their character and a file already exists, it will create a second xml file "NameData2.xml" and so forth until a maximum of 3 files is reached,  ( so the user has differant characters to choose from ) however at the moment it is simply creating 2 xml files at once all containing the same name ( i would guess this is due to them checking all at once in the same if else statements possibly? all i could find when trying to find an answer was how to check for a files existence and if it cant find it how to create one, i will post my code below if anyone has any suggestions that would be brilliant as im quite stumped!

Thankyou in advance.

```
    // This will save the users generated name in a created file
    // NameData.xml and will take the user to the partySelectionScreen.
    private void continueButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            NameSavingInformation nameInfo = new NameSavingInformation();
            nameInfo.GeneratedName = generatedNameTexbox.Text;
            SaveXml.SaveData(nameInfo, "NameData.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        } 

        if(File.Exists("NameData.xml"))
        {
            NameSavingInformation nameInfo = new NameSavingInformation();
            nameInfo.GeneratedName = generatedNameTexbox.Text;
            SaveXml.SaveData(nameInfo, "NameData2.xml");
        } 
        else if (File.Exists("NameData2.xml"))
        {
            NameSavingInformation nameInfo = new NameSavingInformation();
            nameInfo.GeneratedName = generatedNameTexbox.Text;
            SaveXml.SaveData(nameInfo, "NameData3.xml");
        }
        else if (File.Exists("NameData3.xml"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have passed the limit of existing characters" +
                "To continue please return to the main menu and delete at least 1 character");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this.
This will perform a a search on the files that doesn't exists and will generate them. This will permit the user to delete any character the wants without breaking the algorithm.

```
private void continueButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(!File.Exists("NameData.xml"))
    {
        SaveFileInfo("NameData.xml");
    } 
    else if (!File.Exists("NameData2.xml"))
    {
        SaveFileInfo("NameData2.xml");
    }
    else if (!File.Exists("NameData3.xml"))
    {
        SaveFileInfo("NameData3.xml");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have passed the limit of existing characters" +
            "To continue please return to the main menu and delete at least 1 character");
    }
}

public SaveFileInfo(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        NameSavingInformation nameInfo = new NameSavingInformation();
        nameInfo.GeneratedName = generatedNameTexbox.Text;
        SaveXml.SaveData(nameInfo, fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    } 
}
```

Comment: that is wonderful thank you so much for taking the time to answer!